# Set Leaflet Overlay Off in the Layer Control

Tags: javascript, css, html, leaflet

Could someone help me to figure out how to set a leaflet overlay **OFF** by default when adding it to the map, please? For instance, setting the *CITIES* layer **OFF** on the map, as shown in the code below. The point is to have only the *STATES* layer **ON** and the *CITIES* **OFF** by default.

```
var baseMaps = {
    "Grayscale": grayscale, 
    "Streets": streets
};

var overlayMaps = {
    "Cities": cities, // Need to set OFF over the map
    "States": states  // Need to set ON  over the map
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 16):

You should not add it to the map in the first place. Somewhere before that code you posted you initialize the cities layer and add it to the map. Otherwise it wouldn't be on the map. For example:

```
var cities = new L.GeoJSON(...);
cities.addTo(map);

//Or

var cities = new L.GeoJSON(...);
map.addLayer(cities);
```

Now when you add that to your layer control it's checkbox is automaticly checked by the control because it's already added to your map.

Example added after comment for clarification. Here is one layergroup added to the map and the other is not. Both are added to the layer control. Only the one that is added to the map is checked in the control:

```js
var map = new L.Map('leaflet', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0,
    layers: [
        new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
    ]
});

// LAYERGROUP WITH ADD TO MAP
var layerGroup1 = new L.LayerGroup([
    new L.Marker([25, 25])
]).addTo(map);

// LAYERGROUP WITHOUT ADD TO MAP
var layerGroup2 = new L.LayerGroup([
    new L.Marker([-25, -25])
]);

var layerControl = new L.Control.Layers(null, {
    'Group 1': layerGroup1,
    'Group 2': layerGroup2
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body, #leaflet {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Leaflet 1.0.3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @iH8. I understand that. The point is: I need the cities layer in the layer control, but the checkbox must be unchecked when the map is loaded for the first time.

Comment: I don't think you understand what i mean. I've added an example. I hope that clarifies it for you.

Comment: No need to compliment, it's what we are here for. You could however consider to accept the answer if it solved your problem so that others with a similar problem can find a working solution too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't vote Up, but I agree your apportation, It works! My code:

```
var cities = L.layerGroup().addTo(mymap);

L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(cities),
L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(cities),
L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(cities),
L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(cities);

var poligons = L.layerGroup();
L.polygon([[41.5040,1.8047],[41.5037,1.8237],[41.4935,1.82467],[41.4955,1.80210]]).bindPopup('A great polygon').addTo(poligons);

var overlays = {
    "Cities": cities,
    "<span style='color:red;'>Polígons<span>": poligons
};

L.control.layers(null,overlays,{collapsed:false}).addTo(mymap);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to turn the layer off by default, you can set the checked of input element to false after you add all the layer to map, and after all click a random input element of layer will make it work.

for example : i only want to keep the first layer, and set others layer off by default.

```js
// add the all layer to map
L.control.layers(basemaps, markerGroups).addTo(map);
// this can get all input element of layer
var click_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("leaflet-control-layers-selector");
// set all layers off in addtion to the first layer
for (let i = 1;i < click_elements.length;i++) {
     click = click_elements[i];
     click.checked = false;
}
// and finally, make a click event
var first_layer = click_elements[0];
first_layer.click();
```